# how to include javascript in markdown

Tags: javascript, module, markdown, share, embed

i'm try to share document use markdown.(document == html)

but markdown is only suitable for reading.

if other people shared my document, i want to put something like that in the document and get the right results.

for example,
inner html input tag, type="text" id="int",
and then, unnder the line, input tag, type="text" id="result" show input and result value.

but haroopad(i'm use this) dose not support embedded javascript.

how to embed or include javascript in markdown?

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool.  But if you really want to do this kind of thing you will probably need to develop a custom extension to the markdown rendering engine that you are using.  Or maybe pick a markdown engine that supports this kind of thing natively.  Because this is NOT expressible in standard markdown.

Comment: @Stephen C  thank you. can you recommend rendering engine?

Comment: Nope.  Requests for software recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @minsubso see e.g. https://pandoc.org/filters.html